# Symfony4 double entity on create

Tags: symfony, email, symfony4

I am creating a simple mailer..
First you need to create a MailTemplate (Entity).
This exists of a subject, mailFrom and a Message.
Then you create the mail: This happens in two steps.
First you choose your account(s) to send to and your MailTemplate.
Then you redirect to another route where i set the subject, message and mailfrom, so i can adjust things.

When i send (Save the mail). it saved the mail but makes a copy of my MailTemplate and saved the Mailtemplate to.
So i got 1 mail and 2 Templates.

My Template entity

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: david
 * Date: 26-6-2018
 * Time: 20:13
 */

namespace App\Project\MailBundle\Entity;

use App\Project\BaseBundle\Entity\BaseEntity;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Class MailTemplates
 * @package App\Project\MailBundle\Entity
 */

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Project\MailBundle\Repository\MailTemplatesRepository")
 */
class MailTemplate extends BaseEntity
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->active = true;
        $this->bulkmails = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->mails = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @var string $template
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="template", type="string", length=191, nullable=false)
     *
     *
     */
    private $template;

    /**
     * @var string $mailFrom
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=191, nullable=false, options={"default": "noreply@nachtpost.be"})
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     *
     */
    private $mailFrom;

    /**
     * @var string $mailSubject
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=191, nullable=false)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     *
     */
    private $mailSubject;

    /**
     * @var string $mailMessage
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=false)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     *
     */
    private $mailMessage;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Project\MailBundle\Entity\Mail", mappedBy="mailTemplate", orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $mails;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Project\MailBundle\Entity\BulkMail", mappedBy="mailTemplate", orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $bulkmails;

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTemplate(): ? string
    {
        return $this->template;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $template
     */
    public function setTemplate(string $template): void
    {
        $this->template = $template;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getMailFrom()
    {
        return $this->mailFrom;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $mailFrom
     */
    public function setMailFrom($mailFrom): void
    {
        $this->mailFrom = $mailFrom;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getMailSubject()
    {
        return $this->mailSubject;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $mailSubject
     */
    public function setMailSubject($mailSubject): void
    {
        $this->mailSubject = $mailSubject;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getMailMessage()
    {
        return $this->mailMessage;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $mailMessage
     */
    public function setMailMessage($mailMessage): void
    {
        $this->mailMessage = $mailMessage;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getMails(): collection
    {
        return $this->mails;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $mails
     */
    public function setMails($mails)
    {
        $this->mails = $mails;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getBulkmails(): collection
    {
        return $this->bulkmails;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $bulkmails
     */
    public function setBulkmails($bulkmails)
    {
        $this->bulkmails = $bulkmails;
    }



    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->getTemplate();
    }

}
```

My mailEntity

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: david
 * Date: 26-6-2018
 * Time: 20:13
 */

namespace App\Project\MailBundle\Entity;

use App\Project\BaseBundle\Entity\BaseEntity;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;


/**
 * Class BulkMail
 * @package App\Project\MailBundle\Entity
 */

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Project\MailBundle\Repository\BulkMailRepository")
 */
class BulkMail extends BaseEntity
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->mailTo = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->active = true;

    }

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Project\MailBundle\Entity\MailTemplate", inversedBy="mails", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="bulkMail_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
    private $mailTemplate;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Project\AccountBundle\Entity\Account")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="account_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $mailTo;

    /**
     * @var string $mailFrom
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=191, nullable=true)
     *
     */
    private $mailFrom;

    /**
     * @var string $mailSubject
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=191, nullable=true)
     *
     */
    private $mailSubject;

    /**
     * @var string $mailMessage
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     *
     */
    private $mailMessage;


    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getMailTo()
    {
        return $this->mailTo;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $mailTo
     */
    public function setMailTo($mailTo): void
    {
        $this->mailTo = $mailTo;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getMailFrom()
    {
        return $this->mailFrom;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $mailFrom
     */
    public function setMailFrom($mailFrom): void
    {
        $this->mailFrom = $mailFrom;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getMailSubject()
    {
        return $this->mailSubject;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $mailSubject
     */
    public function setMailSubject($mailSubject): void
    {
        $this->mailSubject = $mailSubject;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getMailMessage()
    {
        return $this->mailMessage;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $mailMessage
     */
    public function setMailMessage($mailMessage): void
    {
        $this->mailMessage = $mailMessage;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $accountId
     */
    public function setMail($account): void
    {
        $this->account = $account;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getMailTemplate()
    {
        return $this->mailTemplate;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $mailTemplate
     */
    public function setMailTemplate($mailTemplate)
    {
        $this->mailTemplate = $mailTemplate;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->mailSubject;
    }
}
```

My controller

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: david
 * Date: 5-7-2018
 * Time: 22:41
 */

namespace App\Project\MailBundle\Controller;

use App\Project\AccountBundle\Entity\Account;
use App\Project\MailBundle\Entity\BulkMail;
use App\Project\MailBundle\Entity\MailTemplate;
use App\Project\MailBundle\Forms\BulkAddMailAdminType;
use App\Project\MailBundle\Forms\bulkSelectmailAdminType;
use App\Project\BaseBundle\Controller\BaseController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;


class BulkMailController extends BaseController
{
    public function BulkMailIndexAction()
    {
        $MailRepository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(BulkMail::class);
        $items = $MailRepository->findAll();
        return $this->render('@ProjectMail/mails/bulk/index.html.twig', array(
            'items' => $items
        ));
    }

    public function bulkSelectAction(Request $request) {

        $mail = new BulkMail();

        $form = $this->createForm(BulkSelectmailAdminType::class, $mail);

        if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {

            $form->handleRequest($request);

            if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
                $TemplateRepository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(MailTemplate::class);
                $tId = $mail->getMailTemplate()->getId();
                $template = $TemplateRepository->findOneBy(array('id' => $tId));
                $mail->setMailSubject($template->getMailSubject());
                $mail->setMailFrom($template->getMailFrom());
                $mail->setMailMessage($template->getMailMessage());
                $mail->setMailTemplate($template);

                $this->container->get('session')->set('Bmail', $mail);

                $response = $this->redirectToRoute('mailBulkSend');
                return $response;
            }
        }

        $label = "Email opmaken";
        $response = $this->render('@ProjectMail/mails/bulk/addBulk_select.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'label' => $label
        ));

        return $response;

    }

    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @param \Swift_Mailer $mailer
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function bulkMailAction(Request $request, \Swift_Mailer $mailer) {

        $Bmail = $this->container->get('session')->get('Bmail');

            if ($Bmail) {
                $accounts = array();
                $AccountRepository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Account::class);

                $count = 0;

                foreach ($Bmail->getMailTo() as $key => $account) {
                    $accounts[] = $AccountRepository->findOneById($account->getId());
                    $count ++;
                }

                $form = $this->createForm(BulkAddMailAdminType::class, $Bmail);

                if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {

                    $form->handleRequest($request);

                    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
                        $Bmail->setMailTo($accounts);

                        //dump($Bmail->getMailTemplate()); die;

                        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                        $entityManager->persist($Bmail);
                        $entityManager->flush();

                        // Get account emails in array
                        foreach($accounts as $key => $acc){
                            $persons[$acc->getEmail()] = $acc->getEmail();
                        }


                        $message = (new \Swift_Message($Bmail->getMailSubject()))
                            ->setContentType("text/html")
                            ->setFrom($Bmail->getMailFrom())
                            ->setTo($persons)
                            ->setBody(
                                $this->renderView(
                                    '@ProjectTemplate/_templates/base_mail.html.twig', array(
                                        'type' => 'emailDefault',
                                        'template' => $Bmail
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        ;
                       // $mailer->send($message);


                        $response = $this->redirectToRoute('mailsBulkList');
                        return $response;
                    }
                }

                $label = "Email verzenden";
                $response = $this->render('@ProjectMail/mails/bulk/addMail.html.twig', array(
                    'form' => $form->createView(),
                    'mail' => $Bmail,
                    'accounts' => $accounts,
                    'label' => $label
                ));

            } else {
                $response = $this->redirectToRoute('mailBulkAdd');
            }

        return $response;
    }

    public function deleteAction(BulkMail $mail)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->remove($mail);
        $em->flush();
        return $this->redirectToRoute('mailsBulkList');
    }
}
```

I dont know why this happens and how to handle this right..
Suggestions? Ty in advance!!

Comment: Can you please explain the desired behavior? What do you want to happen and what do you want **not** to happen?

Comment: It should not create a double MailTemplate. Just make a relation to it.
So i can build prebuild mails.

Comment: I'm not quite sure why you are storing the entities in session - but that could be the reason for the issues; please take a look at https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/cookbook/entities-in-session.html for some more information about this. Just as a side note - in the `bulkSelectAction` - why are you getting the template again from the repository and setting it again on the mail when it looks like that entity is already attached there (you are getting the id from the original entity in the beginning so based on that it looks like it exists there already)?

Comment: Too tired to check your code now. Make sure that you do not manually persist the entity while it is already defined in a parent entity with cascade persist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help guys, really appreciated!

After some debugging i came out with this..
Not sure if its the way it should be but it works..
I save my mail in the first action and pass the id in my session, in the second action i pass the mail thru the form, (Can make changes if i need to) and send(Save it again).

Did some cleanup to :)

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: david
 * Date: 5-7-2018
 * Time: 22:41
 */

namespace App\Project\MailBundle\Controller;

use App\Project\AccountBundle\Entity\Account;
use App\Project\MailBundle\Entity\BulkMail;
use App\Project\MailBundle\Entity\MailTemplate;
use App\Project\MailBundle\Forms\BulkAddMailAdminType;
use App\Project\MailBundle\Forms\bulkSelectmailAdminType;
use App\Project\BaseBundle\Controller\BaseController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;


class BulkMailController extends BaseController
{
    public function BulkMailIndexAction()
    {
        $MailRepository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(BulkMail::class);
        $items = $MailRepository->findAll();
        return $this->render('@ProjectMail/mails/bulk/index.html.twig', array(
            'items' => $items
        ));
    }

    public function bulkSelectAction(Request $request) {

        $mail = new BulkMail();

        $form = $this->createForm(BulkSelectmailAdminType::class, $mail);

        if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {

            $form->handleRequest($request);

            if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
                $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $template = $mail->getMailTemplate();
                $mail->setMailSubject($template->getMailSubject());
                $mail->setMailFrom($template->getMailFrom());
                $mail->setMailMessage($template->getMailMessage());

                $entityManager->persist($mail);
                $entityManager->flush();
                $this->container->get('session')->set('Bmail', $mail->getId());

                $response = $this->redirectToRoute('mailBulkSend');
                return $response;
            }
        }

        $label = "Email opmaken";
        $response = $this->render('@ProjectMail/mails/bulk/addBulk_select.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'label' => $label
        ));

        return $response;

    }

    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @param \Swift_Mailer $mailer
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function bulkMailAction(Request $request, \Swift_Mailer $mailer) {

        $BmailId = $this->container->get('session')->get('Bmail');

            if ($BmailId) {
                $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $mailRepo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(BulkMail::class);
                $Bmail = $mailRepo->find($BmailId);

                $accounts = array();
                $AccountRepository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Account::class);

                $count = 0;

                foreach ($Bmail->getMailTo() as $key => $account) {
                    $accounts[] = $AccountRepository->findOneById($account->getId());
                    $count ++;
                }

                $form = $this->createForm(BulkAddMailAdminType::class, $Bmail);

                if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {

                    $form->handleRequest($request);

                    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
                        $Bmail->setMailTo($accounts);

                        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                        $entityManager->persist($Bmail);
                        $entityManager->flush();

                        // Get account emails in array
                        foreach($accounts as $key => $acc){
                            $persons[$acc->getEmail()] = $acc->getEmail();
                        }

                        $message = (new \Swift_Message($Bmail->getMailSubject()))
                            ->setContentType("text/html")
                            ->setFrom($Bmail->getMailFrom())
                            ->setTo($persons)
                            ->setBody(
                                $this->renderView(
                                    '@ProjectTemplate/_templates/base_mail.html.twig', array(
                                        'type' => 'emailDefault',
                                        'template' => $Bmail
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        ;
                       // $mailer->send($message);


                        $response = $this->redirectToRoute('mailsBulkList');
                        return $response;
                    }
                }

                $label = "Email verzenden";
                $response = $this->render('@ProjectMail/mails/bulk/addMail.html.twig', array(
                    'form' => $form->createView(),
                    'mail' => $Bmail,
                    'accounts' => $accounts,
                    'label' => $label
                ));

            } else {
                $response = $this->redirectToRoute('mailBulkAdd');
            }

        return $response;
    }

    public function deleteAction(BulkMail $mail)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->remove($mail);
        $em->flush();
        return $this->redirectToRoute('mailsBulkList');
    }
}
```